# Plink always read the wrong default key file

Tags: windows, putty

I was wondering, where does plink get its default private key file?

If I do not specific any key file, it always pick the following private key file.

```
C:\putty\digitalocean.ppk
```

---

Even though I have ensure Pageant only load 1 Github private key file (Located in C:\putty\github2.ppk)

Somehow, Plink still always pick up `C:\putty\digitalocean.ppk`

I have

1. Reinstall Putty
2. Remove everything in `C:\Users\yccheok\.ssh`

Still, I am getting

```
C:\Users\yccheok>plink.exe -v git@github.com
Looking up host "github.com" for SSH connection
Connecting to 20.205.243.166 port 22
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.76
Connected to 20.205.243.166
Remote version: SSH-2.0-babeld-e1420b26
Using SSH protocol version 2
No GSSAPI security context available
Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256 (unaccelerated)
Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/rsa-sha2-512/rsa-sha2-256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-ed25519 255 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) outbound encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 (unaccelerated) outbound MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) inbound encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 (unaccelerated) inbound MAC algorithm
Reading key file "C:\putty\digitalocean.ppk"
Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
Pageant has 2 SSH-2 keys
Pageant key #0 matches configured key file
Using username "git".
Trying Pageant key #0
Server refused our key
Offered public key
Server refusServer refused our key
ed our key
No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
FATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
```

---

May I know, why is it so? How can I ensure plink pick up the private key file loaded in Pageant?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC plink uses the PuTTy settings. These are saved in the registry and are not removed when you uninstall PuTTy.

The location in the registry:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\Default%20Settings
```

You can either edit the registry settings manually, or you open PuTTy, remove the key from the Default settings and store it again with the name `Default Settings`.

Location: Connection -> SSH -> Auth

This should be picked up by plink as well.